Where should I install packages in my AWS EC2 instance with no storage?
I'm trying to yum install a package on my EC2 instance, but my instance is out of memory. I'm on a t2.medium instance, with 8GiB of memory and no storage, using Amazon Linux.
I would think the solution is to create an EBS with plenty of storage and install the package there, however it seems that yum install in a custom location is not recommended, based on this post.
What is the best practice in this situation?

Side-note: The term "out of memory" normally applies to RAM, not disk space. When you say that you have "no storage", so you mean that you have run out of disk space? If so, you can Modify your Amazon EBS Volume to add additional storage. Then just reboot your instance and it will be detected.

And to be perfectly clear:  There is no EC2 instance without storage.  Your EC2 instance has 8GiB of storage that can be upgraded as suggested, it has 4 GiB of memory.

That makes sense -- I believe I've been confusing RAM and disk space. Also, AWS instance documentation states that the t2.medium instance type has 4GiB of memory and "EBS-Only" storage. Is the 8GiB of storage that you speak of some kind of included EBS, that does not need to be set up separately?
